# How to automatically remove dead package repositories in Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I manage couple of Debian servers and occasionally repositories stop working, and `apt update` gives something like this:

```
Get:25 https://packages.sury.org jessie/main amd64 Packages
Err https://packages.sury.org jessie/main amd64 Packages
  HttpError404
...
W: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  HttpError404
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Is there a way to remove (disable) those dead repositories without manually editing sources files on every server?
`apt-add-repository -r "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie main"`, `apt-add-repository -r "https://packages.sury.org/"` or similar command doesn't seem to do anything. Scripting it is an option (`apt update|grep|cut|sed` and so on...) but is there a proper, less clumsy way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not installed by default in debian

If you have installed a repository through , it can be removed by

```
add-apt-repository –remove ppa:ppa-name
```

or:

```
add-apt-repository –r ppa:ppa_name
```

Or using `ppa-purge` on Ubuntu and Ubuntu derivatives:

```
sudo ppa-purge -o ppa-owner
```

On debian you can check the content of `/etc/apt/sources.d/` dir:

```
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

and remove the `repo.list`

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/repo.list
```